# Incorrectly sent funds to ETH contract address

Tags: etherscan

I incorrectly sent WETH to a contract address (transaction hash is 0x68f9ae5adaf1a411aaabe08a226a0beadc156aa9469ac38ce6b8a6fd6e8027a0). The recipient is 0x82aF49447D8a07e3bd95BD0d56f35241523fBab1. How can I retrieve the funds. Really appreciate the help. thank you

Comment: Can you be more specific what were you trying to do and how you ended up transferring eth to that address

Comment: Was trying to transfer weth from uniswap wallet to my coinbase wallet but instead sent it to a wrong address which i believe is a contract address and not a private wallet address. is there any hope to retrieve the funds? I can see that the transaction is successful in etherscan.

Comment: Is there a way to tell who this address belongs to and if its possible to reach them - 0x82aF49447D8a07e3bd95BD0d56f35241523fBab1

Answer (score 0):

Its (0x82af49447d8a07e3bd95bd0d56f35241523fbab1) a EOA address. The only way you can retrieve your weth is if he sends it back to you. If you goto this link https://etherscan.io/address/0x82af49447d8a07e3bd95bd0d56f35241523fbab1 you will find a message icon which is a link for blockscan chat. Try to contact him.

You could also take professional service help such as - https://bitcoinrecovery.co/cryptocurrencies/ethereum

This is a service dedicated to do recover crypto and is paid.

Comment: thank you for the recommendation.